# IPhone Issues with autosizing cell based on text input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using the below code to try and automatically space out my cell height to the amount of text in the cell. At the moment it works but adds whitespace to the top and the bottom of the cell (say if theres 10 lines, theres 4 lines before and after, but if it's 200 lines theres 40 lines above and below (as in the screenshot) so it's becoming a bit of a pain!)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    AssessObject *newObj1;
    newObj1=[totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];


    cell.textLabel.text = newObj1.routeImage;

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];


    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


{
    AssessObject *newObj1;
    newObj1=[totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *cellText = newObj1.routeImage;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(190.0, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height;

}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're using two different font sizes when calculating your height and on the actual label.  That is very likely to blame for the extra space.

EDIT:

Taking another look, the width you're using when calculating the size is only 190.  From the screenshots you supplied, it looks like your label is quite a bit wider than that.  Make sure the dimensions, font sizes, and line break modes you're using in the actual label are correctly mirrored when calculating the size.  My initial answer is probably not correct, since you're using a larger size in the actual label than the one you're calculating with.